# Как правильно имплементировать метод __str__ для класса?

Tags: python, ооп

Помогите найти ошибку в коде.
Существует класс с атрибутом self.lst: List[List[str]]

Нужно вернуть строку высотой равной количеству внутренних списков и шириной равной количеству элементов во внутренних списках.

```
def __str__(self) -> str:
    """
    >>> self.lst = [['1', '-', '2'], ['3', '-', '-']]
    >>> print(self.lst)
    1-2
    3--
    >>> str(lst)
    >>> '1-2\\n3--'
    """
    mystr = ''
    for l in self.lst:
        for i in l:
            if l.index(i) != len(l) - 1:
                mystr= mystr + i
            elif l.index(i) == len(l) - 1:
                mystr = mystr + i + '\n'
    return mystr

В этом коде метод возвращает только '1-23--'
```

Comment: При вводе в консоль выражения, которое возвращает значение, для него выполняется repr(), соответственно получается экранирование всех спецсимволов в строке, поэтому разный вид одной и той же строки это абсолютно нормально. Но я так и не понял, в чём у вас проблема и чего конкретно вы хотите добиться

Comment: Изменил описание. Не могу понять в чем состоит ошибка в лупе

Comment: Во-первых, если какой-то элемент повторяется в списке несколько раз (а у вас `'-'` повторяется), то метод `index` вернёт индекс только первого экземпляра элемента в массиве. Во-вторых, в показанном вами коде используется какая-то несуществующая переменная `j` и поэтому этот код в принципе неработоспособен

Answer (score 0):

```
for l in self.lst:
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if i != len(l) - 1:
            mystr= mystr + l[i]
        elif i == len(l) - 1 and l != self.lst[-1]
            mystr = mystr + l[i] + '\n'
        elif i == len(l) - 1 and l == self.lst[-1]
            mystr = mystr + l[i]
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Без лишних заморочек и подсчетов длин строк. Для тестов создам и класс:

```py
class Ls:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        result =[]
        for item in self.lst:
            result.append(''.join(item))
        return '\n'.join(result)
```

Протестируем

```py
lists = {1:[], 
        2:[['1', '-', '2'], ['3', '-', '-']],
        3: [['1', '-', '2'], ['3', '-', '-'],['1', '-', '2']]}

for key, value in lists.items():
    l_obj = Ls(value)
    print(f"Test number {key}.\n{l_obj}")
```

вывод

```
Test number 1.

Test number 2.
1-2
3--
Test number 3.
1-2
3--
1-2
```